# Swagger codegen for React Native

Tags: react-native, swagger

I'm a fresher with Javascript and React Native.
My current project is a cross-platform app (PC, Web, Android and IOS) so they use Swagger to create API and document.
I'm using React Native to develop mobile version of this project but I dont know how to generate React Native code from Swagger and use it in my project.

Any help? Thanks!

Comment: Hey! Now I’m in trouble with the same issue. Did you find any solutions?

Comment: Hi @cafedeichi, I generate Swagger to Javascript. Then copy to my project, npm install all dependencies (superagent, querystring) and add "browser": {
  "fs": false
 } to "dependencies" in package.json file.
Or you can npm install the javascript folder directly

Answer (score 0):

I created a tool so that you can use it.
https://github.com/hosseinmd/swagger-typescript.
This module will generate a services.ts/js for you to include all APIs of swagger. Swagger-typescript using axios internally